# Angular 2 - cant load demo libraries (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: angular

OK I am stumped: Is there a basic, minimal, working Angular 2 tutorial for Visual Studio 2015 [image]that actually works?

I've attempted numerous tutorials including the official one:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Believe it or not, at the time of writing this post this example does not work - throws a 404 for numerous dependencies referenced in the NPM package.json file (as for the others tuts, well they reference a lot of beta removed or non-existing references).

I mean, where do you actually download Angular 2 Typings from? They are certainly not listed with the rest of the library on the official site: https://code.angularjs.org/

It actually seems to be impossibly complicated to create an Angular 2 application in Visual Studio that does not require a mass of dependencies and actually works.

Is it just me or are other members of the VS dev community experiencing the same?

output for NPM package.json:

```
npm WARN package.json angular-quickstart@1.0.0 No README data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/reflect-metadata
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/systemjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular2-in-memory-web-api
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-server
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lite-server
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/canonical-path
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-core
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-chrome-launcher
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-htmlfile-reporter
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/common
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/forms
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/upgrade
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tslint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typings
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/concurrently
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/systemjs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/reflect-metadata
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular2-in-memory-web-api
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-server
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lite-server
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-core
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-chrome-launcher
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-htmlfile-reporter
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/canonical-path
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'angular/core' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'angular-quickstart'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\\\node\\node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd D:\www\WebApplication1\WebApplication1
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code E404
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/upgrade
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/common
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tslint
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/forms
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/concurrently
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm

====npm command completed with exit code 1====
```

Comment: Have you tried to update `node` and `npm` versions? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#prereq `Our examples require node v5.x.x or higher and npm 3.x.x or higher`

Comment: Yes, latest and greatest V6 from here: https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Can you print `node -v` and `npm -v`?

Comment: C:\>node -v
v6.6.0

C:\>npm -v
3.10.3

Comment: I think you should post the entire text of the error instead of image.

Comment: Have you checked this thread https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8473?

Comment: Turns out visual studio was shipped with an out of date version of node, which it used by default. I described the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 is shipped with some external tools. So despite having installed the latest version of Node, it was using its own shipped versions which are naturally out of date.

To get VS to use the latest installed version I did the following:

- Open: Tools -> Options
- Find: External Web Tools
- Add: $(PATH) to the TOP of the list (or above path to external tools)

For more information read this article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/03/19/customize-external-web-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/